# mysql query showing error

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, mysql-workbench

MySQL query:-

```
  SET  \`products_id\`=(SELECT COALESCE(APR. \`productid\`,
                                         BPR. \`productid\`,
                                         CPR. \`productid\`,
                                         DPR. \`productid\`,
                                         EPR. \`productid\`, 
                                                          '') as productid
    FROM   
    \`gra\`.\`product\` AS APR
    WHERE  APR.\`mfgpartno\` =\`fgt\`.\`products_mfg_part_no\` && \`APR\`.\`manufacturerid\` = \`fgt\`.\`manufacturers_id\`
    LEFT JOIN \`grb\`.\`product\` AS BPR
    ON  BPR.\`mfgpartno\` =\`csv_temp_table\`.\`products_mfg_part_no\` &&  \`BPR\`.\`manufacturerid\` =\`fgt\`.\`manufacturers_id\`
    LEFT JOIN \`grc\`.\`product\` AS CPR
    ON  CPR.\`mfgpartno\` =\`fgt\`.\`products_mfg_part_no\` && \`CPR\`.\`manufacturerid\`=\`fgt\`.\`manufacturers_id\`
    LEFT JOIN \`grd\`.\`product\` AS DPR
    ON  DPR.\`mfgpartno\` =\`fgt\`.\`products_mfg_part_no\` && \`DPR\`.\`manufacturerid\` =\`fgt\`.\`manufacturers_id\`
    LEFT JOIN \`gre\`.\`product\` AS EPR
    ON  EPR.\`mfgpartno\` =\`fgt\`.\`products_mfg_part_no\` && \`EPR\`.\`manufacturerid\`=\`fgt\`.\`manufacturers_id\`)     ;
```

As you can see I'm searching five different tables for the product_id. 
But it shows the following error

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON  APR.`mfgpartno` = `csv_temp_table`.`products_mfg_part_no` && `APR`.`manufactu' at line 64

I've been stuck here for the past few hours. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: omfg down-voters? why!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this query

```
 SET  @products_id=(SELECT COALESCE(APR.`productid`,
                                         BPR.`productid`,
                                         CPR.`productid`,
                                         DPR.`productid`,
                                         EPR.`productid`, 
                                                          '') as productid
    FROM   
    `gra`.`product` AS APR

    LEFT JOIN `grb`.`product` AS BPR
    ON  BPR.`mfgpartno` =`csv_temp_table`.`products_mfg_part_no` &&  `BPR`.`manufacturerid` =`fgt`.`manufacturers_id`
    LEFT JOIN `grc`.`product` AS CPR
    ON  CPR.`mfgpartno` =`fgt`.`products_mfg_part_no` && `CPR`.`manufacturerid`=`fgt`.`manufacturers_id`
    LEFT JOIN `grd`.`product` AS DPR
    ON  DPR.`mfgpartno` =`fgt`.`products_mfg_part_no` && `DPR`.`manufacturerid` =`fgt`.`manufacturers_id`
    LEFT JOIN `gre`.`product` AS EPR
    ON  EPR.`mfgpartno` =`fgt`.`products_mfg_part_no` && `EPR`.`manufacturerid`=`fgt`.`manufacturers_id`  
    WHERE  APR.`mfgpartno` =`fgt`.`products_mfg_part_no` && `APR`.`manufacturerid` = `fgt`.`manufacturers_id`)  ;
```